# background-image behind div columns

Tags: html, css

So I'm new to HTML and CSS and I was trying to create a layout with a header, a centered column and a background made of an image behind that column but I just can't make it work.

This is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html>
<head>
<title>mylayout </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type=text/css
href="style/my1stcss.css" />
</head>      

<body>
<div id="box">                      
<div id="header"></div>      
<div id="column"></div>        
</div>
</body>
 </html>
```

And this is the css stylesheet:

```
html, body {margin:0px; padding:0px
background-image:url (img.jpg)}

#box {
Height:auto   ;
Width:100%   ;
Margin-left:auto;      
Margin-right:auto;    
}
#header {
Height:150px;
Width:100%;                                  
Background-color:red;
}
#column {
Height:600px  ;
Width:50%     ;                              
Margin-left:25%    ;
Background-color:blue;
}
```

Where you see the white, behind that column I'd like to put an image.

Comment: Please provide your html and css code or a JSFiddle link

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to write all your CSS properties in **lowercase**. `Background-color` isn't valid CSS, it must be `background-color`.

Next remove all empty spaces between your CSS values and always add an semicolon `;` at the end. Otherwise your CSS won't take effect.
At last make sure that the path to the image is correct. If not, no image will be shown.

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/F4mgd/1/)** is an jsFiddle example of your provided code with a cute kitty as a background to give you an example of how it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I always created such layouts, following some conventions. So if you woud like to create a centered "main-frame" with a header of fixed height than:

```
<body>
    <div class="center">
       <div class="main-frame"></div>
       <div class="header"></div>
    </div>
</body>


.center {
    width: <must be set, can be percentage>;
    margin: 0px auto;
 }

 .main-frame {
     position: relative;
     margin: <height of header> auto <height of footer> auto;
  }

 .header {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
     height: <height of header>;
  }
```

The same approache for the footer. Please note that the `main-frame` appears before the header and footer in source, otherwise they lie behind the `main-frame` and are not clickable. One could also fix this by using the `z-index`, but I try to use this as less as possible to prevent confusion with z-indices.

Your desired background image can be attached to the "main-frame" using css in the usual way.